# Leave App in .Net 2.0, or upgrade to 4.0?

Tags: .net

I know questions like this have been asked before, and I've viewed a lot of them. I *think* my question is a little different, but if I'm wrong, feel free to point me to another thread.

I have a mature .Net 2.0 application which is used by many people in my company. I compile it using VS2010. What I'm wondering is if there's any reason to upgrade it to 4.0, if I don't need any of 4.0's features? Keep in mind that I do new development in 4.0 - so the question is only about this existing, mature app.

Please don't give me a list of things I can do with 4.0 that I can't do with 2.0. I already know them (or at least most of them). What I want to know is, if I don't intend on using any of the new .Net 4.0 features in this app, should I just leave my app in 2.0, or upgrade it?

And let's assume that my users can be guaranteed to have both versions installed, so that's not an issue.

Perhaps a better question might be, are there any downsides to leaving it in 2.0, if I don't need any of the new 4.0 features?

Comment: There is no compelling reason to re-target when you don't want or need to use the .NET 4 additions.  Isn't that what all those answers you saw before said as well?

Comment: My only concern is for the future support for .Net 2.0.  For that reason, I'm selecting the highest .Net version available on *Windows XP* (my software's minimum requirement.)

Comment: Why not just change the framework version the next time you need to make a change (i.e. new feature, bug fix) and deploy the application?

Comment: Hans- No, all those other comments did *not* say that, at least the way I read them. There were a lot of differing opinions, most of which were blended together with comments talking about the advantages of later versions of .Net. So, that's why I asked!

Comment: wsanville- As others have mentioned, there are edge cases where problems can arise when going to later versions, which means a full regression test. And personally, I try to avoid those when I can. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have commented, upgrading the framework isn't really a problem if you don't want to, at the moment, since the current versions of Visual Studio allow you to target a specific framework.  What might cause issues in the future for you, is if you wish to use some DLLs the others have produced that use/are compiled against the higher framework versions.

Quick answer, dont' upgrade if you don't need any of the newer features, but if you are going to be using some new features in the future, then your app will probably need a full regresion test when you upgrade the framework (there are only a few edge-case breaking changes between 2.0 -> 3.0 -> 4.0 that most people won't have ever hit)

Comment: Thanks. That was the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I would upgrade sooner rather than later, because the longer you wait the harder the upgrade will be. Language incentives aside, if your codebase is too dated it will be very difficult to upgrade to the latest version.